# Why is ASP.NET vNext 'dnu build' not working on OSX

Tags: c#, .net, macos, asp.net-core, dnx

Installed DNVM and DNX on OSX as instructed via https://github.com/aspnet/Home.

I used [generator-aspnet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-aspnet) to create a console application with one source file, Program.cs:

```
using System;

namespace HelloWorldConsole
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

and a package.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {},
    "commands": {
        "run": "run"
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": {},
        "dnxcore50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Console": "4.0.0-beta-*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it using `dnu . run`, it works as expected and prints "Hello World!".

However when I try to generate assemblies from it by running `dnu build` I get the following error:

> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Failed to read past end of stream.
>   at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadChar () [0x00000] in :0    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CvtResFile.ReadStringOrID
>   (System.IO.BinaryReader fhIn) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CvtResFile.ReadResFile (System.IO.Stream
>   stream) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.MakeWin32ResourceList
>   (System.IO.Stream win32Resources, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DiagnosticBag
>   diagnostics) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.SetupWin32Resources
>   (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Emit.PEModuleBuilder moduleBeingBuilt,
>   System.IO.Stream win32Resources, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DiagnosticBag
>   diagnostics) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpCompilation.CompileImpl
>   (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.CommonPEModuleBuilder moduleBuilder,
>   System.IO.Stream win32Resources, System.IO.Stream xmlDocStream,
>   Boolean generateDebugInfo, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DiagnosticBag
>   diagnostics, System.Predicate`1 filterOpt, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.Compile
>   (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.CommonPEModuleBuilder moduleBuilder,
>   System.IO.Stream win32Resources, System.IO.Stream xmlDocStream,
>   Boolean generateDebugInfo, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DiagnosticBag
>   diagnostics, System.Predicate`1 filterOpt, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.Emit
>   (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EmitStreamProvider peStreamProvider,
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EmitStreamProvider pdbStreamProvider,
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EmitStreamProvider
>   xmlDocumentationStreamProvider,
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EmitStreamProvider
>   win32ResourcesStreamProvider, IEnumerable`1 manifestResources,
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.EmitOptions options,
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeGen.CompilationTestData testData,
>   System.Func`1 getHostDiagnostics, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.Emit (System.IO.Stream peStream,
>   System.IO.Stream pdbStream, System.IO.Stream xmlDocumentationStream,
>   System.IO.Stream win32Resources, IEnumerable`1 manifestResources,
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.EmitOptions options,
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeGen.CompilationTestData testData,
>   System.Func`1 getHostDiagnostics, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Compilation.Emit (System.IO.Stream peStream,
>   System.IO.Stream pdbStream, System.IO.Stream xmlDocumentationStream,
>   System.IO.Stream win32Resources, IEnumerable`1 manifestResources,
>   Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Emit.EmitOptions options, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn.RoslynProjectReference.EmitAssembly
>   (System.String outputPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.ProjectBuilder.Build (System.String
>   name, System.String outputPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
>
>   at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.BuildContext.Build
>   (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 diagnostics) [0x00000] in :0    at Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.BuildManager.Build
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.Program+<>c__DisplayClass3_4.b__8
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Common.CommandLine.CommandLineApplication.Execute
>   (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.Framework.PackageManager.Program.Main (System.String[] args)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke
>   (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)   at
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[]
>   parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in
>   :0

Any ideas why dnx . run works but dnu build doesn't? The core libs seem to be getting referenced and loaded hence the run working. What's missing with the dnu build command?

Comment: Looks like it's a known issue with Mono and the bug has been reported. Unfortunately, there's no known work-around. https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/498

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the link will keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What I did is this:

1. clone the mono repository, compile and install it following the directions here http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/ (make sure to follow the directions for compiling from git source)
2. brew tap aspnet/dnx
3. brew upgrade
4. brew install dnvm --without-mono

After doing this I was able to run dnu build successfully.

Comment: Seems the 4.3.0 version runs quite nice. Also a fix has been written. See https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/498 for more info.

Comment: I've tried everything at least 10x and these instructions don't seem to help. This issue seems to have been around for quite awhile, when will it be fixed? Is it mono's or aspnet team's issue? I can't enjoy the goods until this is working :\

Comment: Is there a Linux equivalent to these same steps?  The same problem exists on Linux also, but we don't have "brew".  If these workarounds are known, then why don't they at least update the documentation?  I've been trying off and on for several weeks now, but have yet to see ASP.NET actually running on a Linux box.

Answer (score 4):

It is a known Mono bug: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=29499

Discussion is here: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/498

Answer (score 4):

The issue seems to be brew is pointing at a version of mono that doesn't seem to work well with the latest build of aspnet/dnx. Here is a way to get it pointing to a workable version.

1. nano /usr/local/Library/Formula/mono.rb
2. changed line 4 and 5 to

   url "http://download.mono-project.com/sources/mono/mono-4.0.1.44.tar.bz2"
   sha256 "eaf5bd9d19818cb89483b3c9cae2ee3569643fd621560da036f6a49f6b3e3a6f"
3. brew upgrade mono
4. You should be able to properly run dnu build on the project

   - source dnvm.sh
   - cd projectdir
   - dnu restore
   - dnu build
   - export MONO_MANAGED_WATCHER=false (for mono bug, see link below)
   - dnx . kestrel
   - open http://localhost:5001

about mono bug - [Running first ASP.NET 5 application using VSCode, DNX and kestrel results in IOException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29971826/running-first-asp-net-5-application-using-vscode-dnx-and-kestrel-results-in-ioe)

If you have problems with brew, use brew doctor

Thanks to salerth https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/498

Comment: Thanks, this worked. On my machine, brew upgrade of mono took a while. So if you choose this option, be aware that part can take some time (10 min on my machine). I also had to run dnvm upgrade -u and then dnu restore before things worked-out. Don't know if the latter is always needed.