# Running first ASP.NET 5 application using VSCode, DNX and kestrel results in IOException

Tags: visual-studio-code, dnx, kestrel-http-server

Following the steps described in the [Visual Studio Code documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/ASPnet5), running the final command `dnx . kestrel` via the Command Palette of VSCode on Mac OS X results in an IOException when visiting http://localhost:5001:

```
kqueue() FileSystemWatcher has reached the maximum nunmber of files to watch.
```

See the attached screenshot for the complete stacktrace. What could be wrong?[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's a [known mono bug](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/3.12.0/). In order to fix it set the `MONO_MANAGED_WATCHER` environment variable:

```
export MONO_MANAGED_WATCHER=false
```

[Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/2348)

Comment: Thanks, this seems like a step forward… However, another exception is now thrown: TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.ILibraryExport' from assembly 'Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: @dbaw It is an exception indicating a version mismatch between your .net version and the version the project dependencies have been built against. You can set up a correct version using dnvm. More information can be found in my [blog post](http://andreizubov.blogspot.ru/2015/04/getting-started-with-net-on-os-x-and.html)

Comment: @AndreiZubov A thousand times yes!  The managed_watcher and setting dnvm to use beta 4 active and default did the trick.  Thank you!

Comment: @AndreiZubov This does the trick. I also had to overrule the DNX_FEED variable with 'export DNX_FEED=https://www.nuget.org/api/v2' and force an dnvm upgrade through 'dnvm upgrade -f' because I was on the unstable channel. But made it to the WebApplication main page, thanks!